# Rational canonical form of the Frobenius transformation

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

I am working on a problem from Dummit and Foote 3 ed. (self-study, if it matters).  It is problem 13.6.11, which is the following:

> Let $ \varphi $ denote the Frobenius map $ x\mapsto x^p $ on the finite field $ \mathbb{F}_{p^n} $.  Determine the rational canonical form over $ \mathbb{F}_p $ for $ \varphi $ considered as an $ \mathbb{F}_p $-linear transformation on the $ n $-dimensional $ \mathbb{F}_p $-vector space $ \mathbb{F}_{p^n} $.

I only read, but did not carefully study, the section on rational canonical forms (previous chapter).  From what I can see, there is an algorithm for computing rational canonical forms, but I cannot very well apply an algorithm in an abstract setting.  (I've worked out some small examples like $ p = 3, n = 2 $, but this was not very enlightening about the general case.)

Thinking more abstractly, I know that I am looking for *invariant subspaces*.  Clearly we have an abundance of such subspaces: there are natural inclusions $ \mathbb{F}_{p^d} \subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p^n} $ for divisors $ d|n $, and it's not hard for me to show that each of these is an invariant subspace of $ \varphi $.  In the previous problem I showed that the frobenius transformation $ \varphi $ is a ($\mathbb{F}_p$)-linear isomorphism $ \mathbb{F}_{p^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{p^n} $, and I showed directly that its minimal polynomial $ x^n - 1 $.  (Hence, when restricted to $ \mathbb{F}_{p^d} $, the minimal polynomial is $ x^d - 1 $.)

> Am I on the right track for finding the rational canonical form?  What should I do next?

Comment: take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341215/rational-canonical-form-over-finite-field

Comment: I think you're basically done. The matrix for $\varphi$ is $n \times n$, and since you've shown that $x^n - 1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\varphi$, then the rational canonical form must contain the companion matrix of $x^n-1$ as a block. But this block is $n \times n$, so the whole matrix is just the single $n \times n$ block given by the companion matrix for $x^n -1$.

Comment: @RichardD.James I have to admit I'm rather confused now about what rational canonical form means.  If I am working over the complex numbers and I have a matrix whose minimal polynomial is $ (x - \lambda_1)\cdots(x - \lambda_n) $ (distinct eigenvalues), then isn't the rational canonical form $ \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1 \ldots \lambda_n) $?  Is it not relevant that $ x^n - 1 $ factors as $ x^n - 1 = \prod_{d|n}{\Phi_d(x)} $?  I was thinking maybe these $ \Phi_d $ play a role in the RCF.   Is factorization of the minimal polynomial not relevant?

Comment: @JakeMirra You seem to be thinking of Jordan canonical form.